# Load jQuery inside Page Template

Tags: jquery

This is rather basic, and maybe it's a duplicate question, so let me know where exactly is answered in that case.

I need to add a very simple jQuery script inside my Page Template.
I'm using Openstrap theme and I can see that jQuery is loaded on every page, so I thought I could insert my script normally but doesn't work.

After reading some posts, I've seen that I have to use `wp_enqueued_script` function, however I just need to load the script on the Page Template only, not every page.

---

**edit**

It worked! I changed it to is_singular($post_type) for my needs, and it works as expected. However, the jQuery script isn't doing anything.

Inside functions.php,

```
/* loader iframes */
function loader_iframe() {
if ( is_singular('farmacia') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'loader-iframe', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loader-iframe.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loader_iframe' );
```

Inside js/loader-iframe.js,

```
$(function() {
    $('.loader-iframe').on('load', function(){
        $('.loader-iframe').find('img').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function to first enqueue your script and then [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook to properly add your script to your footer or header of your theme.

Also, you should take a look at [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and how they are used to load functions/scripts/styles/etc on a conditional basis.

So you would do something like this. First create a new file in your themes js folder and call it something like my-script.js. Open in up and add your scripts into that file. You are now ready to add the js file to your theme's header/footer conditionally on a specific page with this function

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
if ( is_page( 42 ) //will check if we are on page ID 42, please see conditional tags or is_page_template( 'about.php' ) to check if the page template is about.php ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' )//only if script is dependant on jquery );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

Comment: thanks, I read something about that, but you made it very clear!